# AnimateCC Canvas calling functions

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I'm trying to change this code that I made from `actionscript 3` to `html5 canvas`. I’m with doubt about calling functions that I created, for example:

```
function cleanSelection(){
    this.a1.visible = true;
    this.sa1.visible = false;

    this.a2.visible = true;
    this.sa2.visible = false;
}

function maxSelection(count){
    cleanSelection();
    count = 0;
    return count;
}
```

I want to make this function below be able to call `maxSelection()` which calls `cleanSelection()`

```
this.a1.addEventListener("click", fl_Click.bind(this));
function fl_Click()
{
   this.sa1.visible = true;
   this.a1.visible = false;
   count++;
   if(count >= 2){
       count = maxSelection(count);
   }
}
```

How can I call these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should put "bind(this)" in all methods:

```
function cleanSelection(){
   this.a1.visible = true;
   this.sa1.visible = false;

   this.a2.visible = true;
   this.sa2.visible = false;
}

function maxSelection(c){
   cleanSelection.bind(this)();
   c= 0;
   return c;
}
var count = 0;
this.a1.addEventListener("click", fl_Click.bind(this));
function fl_Click() {
  this.sa1.visible = true;
  this.a1.visible = false;
  count++;
  if(count >= 2){
     count = maxSelection.bind(this)(count);
  }
```

}